# How to find the bounds of a double integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm so confused with this question:

[image]

I have done the quadratic formula to find $-1 + \sqrt{1-x} \leq y \leq 1 + \sqrt{1-x}$, so $-1 \leq y \leq 1$. But I don't know how to find the x bounds.

I know the graphs intersect.

Answer (score 2):

Where do the curves intersect?  Since, x = f(y) and y=f(x) with the same f, these two curves are symmetric about the line x = y.

The solution to $x = x(2-x)$ will give you your boundaries for x.

$x^2 - x = 0$
the endpoints are x = 0 and x = 1.

As for your y boundaries, you have done something with the signs.

your bounds for y should be:

$1-\sqrt{1-x}\leq y \leq 1+\sqrt{1-x}$
your limit for y is also
$y = 2x - x^2$
One of these is the upper limit, and one of these is the lower limit.

It never hurts to draw a picture.
you have two parabola, at right angles to one another.

$\int_0^1\int_{1-\sqrt{1-x}}^{2x-x^2} x dy dx$

Comment: How do you find where the lines intersect? I know that $y^2 - 2y = -x$ and $ y = 2x - x^2$, Do you solve for $y$ ?

Comment: I don't understand how you know to set $x = x(2-x)$

Comment: Because these two curves represent inverse functions of one another, and inverse functions are symmetric about the line y=x.  If they are symmetric about that line, the point of intersection must be on that line.  So we find the point of intersection of y=x and y=x(2-x)

Comment: Could I have done $\int_0^1 \int_{1-\sqrt{1-x}}^{1 + \sqrt{1-x}} x dy dx$?

Comment: No, and that I why I suggest you draw the picture.

Comment: I see from the picture that I have to use $2x-x^2$, however, how would I have known that had I not drawn the picture? Does the $1- \sqrt{1-x}$ only apply for the lower bound?

Answer (score 1):

If you draw the graph, it is easy to get: The bound for $y$ is
$$ 1-\sqrt{1-x}\le y\le 2x-x^2$$
and the bound for $x$ is $0\le x\le 1$.